# SAPUI5 Logout Event with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, logoff, sapui5

I am currently working on a SAP XS application. Using the provided API, I want to log off my user on the website. Im totally new on Javascript to please dont mind the probable ease of my question.

The API (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.ApplicationHeader.html#event:logoff) provides the method "fireLogoff". But before that I have to add "attachLogoff" to the applicationheader in my application right?

My faulty method looks like this:

```
oAppHeader.attachLogoff(function logout(oEvent) {this.fireLogOff();});
```

Thank you a lot for helping a noob in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

*fireLogOff* calls a function assigned to *logOff*. So you need to write your own code for SAP HANA API that makes user to log off. Or you can just close browser tab:

```
oAppHeader.attachLogoff(function(){window.close();});
```

Comment: I found out that the method .attachLogoff() is sufficient to initiate the logoff, like this: oAppHeader.attachLogoff(function() {alert("Logged out");}) But after clicking the button, nothing happens. Is it correct that I have to implement my own behaviour for the logoff event? Thank you

Comment: Yes, from a sapui5 perspective you need to implement the behaviour of the logoff event. There may be functions in SAP XS you can call, but I am not familiar with it unfortunately